# Reveal.js Custom Keyboard Bindings negate Fade Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, reveal.js

I have about 20 slides, and I have assigned the keyboard reassignments to go to each slide depending on which key you press. I took note of the already assigned key commands as to not overwrite anything important (full screen, next, previous, etc.)

The problem I'm running into is that I can transition from slide 1 to slide 2, slide 1 to slide 3, slide 1 to slide 4, and so on for a bit, but then around slide 6 or 7, the fade simply refuses to work, and it's just a quick cut to the next slide. I'm wondering if I've written something incorrectly in my initialize script.

```
Reveal.initialize({
          controls: false,
          progress: false,
          history: false,
          center: true,
          transition: 'fade',
          transitionSpeed: 'slow',
          loop: true,
          keyboard: {
                    81: function() { Reveal.slide(0) }, // Q Key
                    87: function() { Reveal.slide(1) }, // W Key
                    69: function() { Reveal.slide(2) }, // E Key
                    82: function() { Reveal.slide(3) }, // R Key
                    84: function() { Reveal.slide(4) }, // T Key
                    89: function() { Reveal.slide(5) }, // Y Key
                    85: function() { Reveal.slide(6) }, // U Key
                    73: function() { Reveal.slide(7) }, // I Key
                    219: function() { Reveal.slide(8) }, // [ Key
                    221: function() { Reveal.slide(9) }, // ] Key
                    220: function() { Reveal.slide(10) }, // \ Key
                    65: function() { Reveal.slide(11) }, // A Key
                    68: function() { Reveal.slide(12) }, // D Key
                    71: function() { Reveal.slide(13) }, // G Key
                    186: function() { Reveal.slide(14) }, // ; Key
                    222: function() { Reveal.slide(15) }, // ' Key
                    90: function() { Reveal.slide(16) }, // Z Key
                    88: function() { Reveal.slide(17) }, // X Key
                    67: function() { Reveal.slide(18) }, // C Key
                    77: function() { Reveal.slide(19); } // M Key
          },
          dependencies: [
                    { src: 'lib/js/classList.js', condition: function() { return !document.body.classList; } },
                    { src: 'plugin/markdown/marked.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
                    { src: 'plugin/markdown/markdown.js', condition: function() { return !!document.querySelector( '[data-markdown]' ); } },
                    { src: 'plugin/highlight/highlight.js', async: true, callback: function() { hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); } },
                    { src: 'plugin/search/search.js', async: true },
                    { src: 'plugin/zoom-js/zoom.js', async: true },
                    { src: 'plugin/notes/notes.js', async: true }
          ]
});
```

The documentation on how to properly use the .slide() is mediocre at best.  The documentation clearly states the call is:

```
Reveal.slide( indexh, indexv, indexf );
```

But it never actually says what indexh, indexv or indexf are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `viewDistance` parameter in the initialisation options to be larger than the number of slides, eg...

```
Reveal.initialize({
    //...
    viewDistance: 20
});
```

By default, reveal uses lazy loading of slides to preload slides that are within a certain 'distance' of the current slide, and unload slides that are further away. This is primarily used to load and unload media that use the `data-src` attribute, but it also hides the slides by setting the slides style to `display: none`. In your case the slide transition does not occur when the jumping to a slide further than 3 slides ahead as the slide is not displayed before the transition. Setting a large `viewDistance` will avoid this, but beware that this will circumvent any lazy loading media you have configured.

As for the `Reveal.slide( indexh, indexv, indexf )` function:

- `indexh` is the horizontal index of the slide
- `indexv` is the vertical index of the slide
- `indexf` is the index of the fragment within the target slide

When you call `Reveal.slide(1)` you're not actually changing to slide 1 but you're changing to the second horizontal slide (0-indexed). I assume you don't have any vertical slides so the indexes will match the numbers directly.

Comment: Technically I think this is a bug -  see comment in [Issue #2113](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/2113), but the `viewDistance` workaround should work for you